# Search value in text and highlight it

Tags: jquery

So what I've so far is a plugin which pretend to work like `<select>` but with few changes.

There is search field in it, and what I want to do is highlight value that is found (or make text with `decoration: underline`).

**Problem is, I don't know how to properly operate with values**, and completely don't have and idea how I can insert tags (like `<div>` or `<i>`) before and after value that was found.

JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/kspD8/

You can find code which performs operations on search in line 269:

```
$this.find('.ms-column:contains("' + value + '")').parents('.multiple-selector-table-row').show();
```

If you are not able to find it, look for section:

```
/* 
===========================================================
    Keyup in search field
===========================================================
*/
```

Please note that due to plugin logic, you will not be able to select any other field, other than you've selected before (not a bug, just warning).

If you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: where is the search field? i couldnt find it

Comment: Click on any field and table will appear below. In top of table there is a field which is a search field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As friend said, you have to use a highlight plugin as:

http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

Update you code this lines:

instead of using:

```
$this.find('.ms-search').keyup(function(event){
```

use:

```
$this.find('.ms-search').on('input',function(event){
```

and then, inside your `'if'`s use:

```
$this.find('.ms-column:contains("' + value + '")').highlight(value);
```

it will wrap the text you type in your `.ms-search` with a `<span class="highlight">value</span>`

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/KasH3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin for this...
http://hugoware.net/blog/more-jquery-magic-search-highlighting

Comment: This plugin using very small piece of code. You can use it direct. They have used preg_replace function to search & add some class to highlight it. Once look at this. You can use just concept...